# a sample to create intro for android application

Tags: android, sample

I want to find a sample of an intro for my application.to be more clear I want something like intro of `SoundCloud` application or `linkedin` (when you first time run them you see some pages like slideshows with texts and animations) but I don't know what keywords to search or what libraries I can use?Can you please help me find a solution for my problem
Thank you so much

Comment: ViewFlipper it is called as!

Comment: @Skynet thank you ,I looked at it and it seems what I need ,Thanks

Comment: I guess it's SoundCloud.

Comment: @IndexOutOfBounds oh yes,My mistake..sorry,I edited the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) or [ViewFlipper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html).

Here is the good example for auto sliding images

https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider